# How to push/navigate a content page of xamarin form from xamarin.iOS RowSelect method

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a content page which contains a iOS native UITableView which I have implemented using Listview renderer. I am trying to push a content page on click of tableView cell in RowSelected method along with the argument. Which I am not able to do it. Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: you should add the code that you have tried

Comment: ListView in Xamarin.Forms is one of the most powerful controls - why use a custom iOS implementation? To help you with your question: there is a sample at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Native2Forms/FormsBasics.iOS/MyFirstPage.cs#L29

Comment: @Krumelur Thanks for providing sample link.